# Using dplyr to manipulate header information imbedded in csv

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

First off, I am learning to use dplyr after having used base-r for most of my career (not really a data analyst, but trying to learn). I don't know if dplyr is the best option for this, or if I should use something else.

I have a data file generated by a piece of equipment that is very messy. There are header/tombstone data embedded within the data (time/date/location/sensor data for a specific location between rows of data for that location). The files are relatively large (150,000 observations x 14 variables), and I have successfully used dplyr to separate the actual data from the tombstone data (tombstone data has 6 rows of information spread over the 14 columns).

I am trying to create a single row of the tombstone information to append to the actual measurements so that it can be easily readable in R for analysis without relying on a "blackbox" solution from the manufacturer.

a sample of the data file and my script is provided below:

```
# Read csv file of data into R
data <- read_csv("data.csv", col_names = FALSE)
data
# A tibble: 155,538 x 14
    X1       X2        X3        X4    X5    X6    X7    X8     X9    X10    X11    X12    X13        X14
 <dbl>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1      NA    80.00     19.00      0.00  37.0   1.0   0.0  3.00     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA         NA
2 1.4e+01     8.00      6.00     13.00  43.0   9.0  33.0 50.00   1.00  -1.60  -2.00  50.10  14.88         NA
3 5.9e-01     5.15      2.02     -0.57   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.00  24.58  28.02  25.64  25.37     NA         NA
4 0.0e+00     0.00      0.00      0.00   0.0    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA         NA
5 3.0e+04 30000.00 -32768.00 -32768.00   0.0    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA         NA
6 0.0e+00     0.00      0.00      0.00   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.25  20.30     NA     NA     NA     NA         NA
7 3.7e+01       cm        BT    counts   1.0   0.1    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA         NA
8      NA     0.25     13.30    145.46   7.5 -11.0   2.1  0.80 157.00 149.00 158.00 143.00 100.00 2147483647
9      NA     0.35     13.37    144.54   7.8 -10.9   2.4 -0.40 153.00 150.00 148.00 146.00 100.00 2147483647
10     NA     0.45     14.49    144.65   8.4 -11.8   1.8 -0.90 139.00 156.00 151.00 152.00 100.00 2147483647
# ... with 155,528 more rows

# Get header information from file and create index(ens) of header information to later append header data to each line of measured data
header <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(data[,1])) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(ens = rep(1:(nrow(header)/6), each = 6)) %>%
  group_by(ens) 

n.head <- bind_cols(header[header$ens == 1,][1,], header[header$ens == 1,][2,], header[header$ens == 1,][3,], header[header$ens == 1,][4,], header[header$ens == 1,][5,], header[header$ens == 1,][6,])
```

Rows 2:7 have the information I am trying to work with, I know that creating a row of 90+ variables is not ideal, but this is a first step in cleaning this data up so that I can then work with it.

the last row with `n.head` is what I am hoping to end up with, without needing to write a loop to run that ~20,000 times... Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance for input!

Comment: A couple questions: 1) what's supposed to happen to Row 1? It looks like it's getting dropped altogether. 2) Are you going to eventually append this single row of observations to each row of the rest of the data?

Comment: 1) Row 1 is some basic header information for the whole file, not necessarily useful for analysis. 2)Yes, I am hoping to append the information to each row for the data. Essentially have a Lat/Lon, date/time, and some basic calibration info for each point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use `tidy::spread()` and `tibble::enframe` to get the header columns spread out into a single row data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

header  <- data[2:7] %>% 
  # convert the data frame to a vector
  t %>% 
  as.vector %>% 
  # then change it back into a single row data frame that's in long format
  enframe %>% 
  # then push that back into a wide format, ie. 1 row and a bajillion columns
  spread(name, value)

# replicate the row as many times as you have data
header[2:nrow(actualdata,]  <- header

#use bind_cols() to glue your header rows onto each row of the actual data
actualdata  <- data[7:nrow(data),] %>% 
  bind_cols(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had never even heard of enframe before! I still have some more to do before I get everything working on the full file, but you solved the hurdle that's been tripping me up all day!